# From several polygons of one layer to one polygon

Tags: qgis, merge

I have imported one CSV file where I have zones of the city. Is it possible to get one big polygon of the city?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `dissolve`?

Comment: Using the tool named `dissolve`.

Comment: Thanks! Write your answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `dissolve` indicated by erik, tool which you probably used now, it offer you to dissolve with options.

If you want to merge selected polygons you can also use the `Merge Features` in advanced digitizing, you don't have one big polygons, as `dissolve` tools, but it could be useful depending on what are you looking for.

More over there is a extension : `dissolve with stat` but actually it's not update, works with older version of qgis.